# Redirect www.siteName.net to www.siteName.com via IIS

Tags: redirect, iis

I submit number domain for my site. I need to redirect all domain such as  **www.siteName.net** , **www.siteName.ir** , **www.siteName.co**  to **www.siteName.com** via IIS.

Is this Possible?

If not Possible what is current solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with this rule:

```
<rule name="all domains www.siteName* to www.siteName.com" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.siteName" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.siteName.com" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.siteName.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

It will redirect everything for domains www.siteName* to www.siteName.com